# Java Graphics2D : draw the following figure under the previous

Tags: java, graphics, awt, paint

How can I draw the following figure **under** the previous? Now it's over... It will be funnel, so I want every next oval was under the polygon and arc.
I have such code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < pdLen; i++) {
        ....
        ....
        g2.fillPolygon(poly);

        g2.fillOval(topLeft[0], topLeft[1] - 10, topRight[0] - topLeft[0], arcHeight);

        g2.fillArc(botLeft[0], botLeft[1] - arcHeight / 2, botRight[0] - botLeft[0], arcHeight, 0, -180);
    }
```

Thanks
PS: Following coordinates are calculated from previous, so *for(int i=pdLen-1;i>0;i--){* will not work

**UPD:**

every loop step calculates topLeft and topRight.

```
        int[] topLeft = {(int)Math.round( startX + ( procSum/onePixX ) ), (int)Math.round( startY + ( procSum/onePixY ) )};
        int[] topRight = {(int)Math.round( topRightX - ( procSum/onePixX ) ), (int)Math.round( startY + ( procSum/onePixY ) )};
        procSum += (pieceData[i] * pieceProc);

        int[] botLeft = {(int)Math.round( startX + ( procSum/onePixX ) ), (int)Math.round( startY + ( procSum/onePixY ) )};
        int[] botRight = {(int)Math.round( topRightX - ( procSum/onePixX ) ), (int)Math.round( startY + ( procSum/onePixY ) )};
        procSum += padProc;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reverse the loop. You might have to think about the computation of the coordinates, but it can be done.

In general, in such cases you should post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This will save a lot of time for everybody.

However, the cheap (i.e. simple) solution would be to store what has to be painted, and then paint these shapes in reverse order:

```
List<Shape> ovals = new ArrayList<Shape>();
List<Shape> arcs = new ArrayList<Shape>();
for (int i = 0; i < pdLen; i++) {
    //g2.fillOval(topLeft[0], topLeft[1] - 10, topRight[0] - topLeft[0], arcHeight);
    ovals.add(new Ellipse2D.Double(topLeft[0], topLeft[1] - 10, topRight[0] - topLeft[0], arcHeight));
    //g2.fillArc(botLeft[0], botLeft[1] - arcHeight / 2, botRight[0] - botLeft[0], arcHeight, 0, -180);
    arcs.add(new Arc2D.Double(botLeft[0], botLeft[1] - arcHeight / 2, botRight[0] - botLeft[0], arcHeight, 0, -180));
}
for (int i=ovals.size()-1; i>=0; i--)
{
    g2.fill(ovals.get(i));
    g2.fill(arcs.get(i));
}
```